# When Google disagrees with Google -- Google Maps vs Google Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I have noticed some anomalies comparing output from Maps versus the Geocoding API. I have listed some below (all in Northern Territory, Australia):

```
0822 MIDDLE POINT NT 
Google Geocoding Lat/Long:  -12.5740229, 131.3172785
Google Maps Lat/Long:       -12.5990556, 131.3271378
Great Circle Distance (km): 2.98212
```

[Visual idea of distance](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/-12.5740229,131.3172785/-12.5990556,131.3271378)

3km isn't so bad you might say. Okay, try this one:

```
0822 WEST ARNHEM  NT
Google Geocoding Lat/Long:  -12.2360191, 134.0609589
Google Maps Lat/Long:       -12.238447,  133.7425002
Great Circle Distance (km): 34.60744
```

[Visual idea of distance](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/-12.2360191,134.0609589/-12.238447,133.7425002)

This is a bit more serious. And it gets worse.

```
0852 TANAMI EAST NT 
Google Geocoding Lat/Long:  -16.757906, 132.5049896
Google Maps Lat/Long:       -18.4880085, 132.8082186
Great Circle Distance (km): 195.04384
```

[Visual idea of distance](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/-16.757906,132.5049896/-18.4880085,132.8082186)

Which of the two sources should be taken as canonical?